# Android content provider databse (SQLite) query to update a particular contact data in ListView?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

I'm writing an Chat app for Android. I've faced a certain difficulty which the problem I can't resolve since databases using content providers aren't my expertise. So i figured out maybe one of you could help me out. I currently have a table ( Message ). My goal is to update data in listview for a particular user. I mean now i am chatting with 3 users i have to update the listview with specified user1 data only. My databases is an Android `ContentProvider` (sqlite) and looks like the following.

```
| Message |
| _Id     |
| _from   |
| _to     | 
| _body   | 
| _type   | 
| date    |
```

I am **Inserting data** into table like this.

```
ChatMessage chat_message = new ChatMessage(user_id, from, to, body, "CHAT", date);
context.getContentResolver().insert(ChatMessage.MESSAGE_URI, 
                                               chat_message.getContentValues());
```

I am using this  code to **Update data** in listview like this. it's updating full data available in SQlite, but i want to update if field `_from = user1' like this i have to create query.

```
public class MessageFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnClickListener {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       full_to = getArguments().getString("USER_ID");
       to = getArguments().getString("U_NAME");
       acc_id = getArguments().getString("ACC_ID");      
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.compose_message_activity, container, false);
       return v;
   }

   @Override
   public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       getListView().setDivider(null);      
       mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity(), null);      
       getLoaderManager().initLoader(TUTORIAL_LIST_LOADER, null, this);       
       setListAdapter(mAdapter);          
   }

   @Override
   public void onResume() {       
       super.onResume();       
   }

   @Override
   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();       
   }

   private void loadMessageContent() {

       getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, getArguments(), this);       
       if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(to)) {            
           ContentValues args = new ContentValues();          
           getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ChatMessage.MESSAGE_URI, null,  ChatMessage.FIELD_FROM + "=?", new String[] { to } , null);
       }
   }    

   @Override
   public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {      

       String[] projection = { ChatMessage.FIELD_ID, ChatMessage.FIELD_BODY };
       CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ChatMessage.MESSAGE_URI, projection, null, null, ChatMessage.FIELD_DATE + " ASC");
       return cursorLoader;
   }

   @Override
   public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
       mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
   }

   @Override
   public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
       mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with updating the whole `Cursor`?

Comment: It's updating whole cursor, but i want to get a particular user data only, i mean in the data has a data with 100 rows in that column _from is only 3 different user names, if i want to chat with user1 i have to update only user1 data in list view if it has any history and present data what i am sending to the user1. if u did't get let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days struggling finally i got a solution for my requirement. by using this i am able get the required data from database.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.i(THIS_FILE, "Content Changes ");        
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ChatMessage.MESSAGE_URI, null,  ChatMessage.FIELD_FROM + "=?", new String[] { to } , ChatMessage.FIELD_DATE + " ASC" );
    return cursorLoader;
}
```